# ¿Como muestro los registros de una tabla en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
DROP DATABASE escuela;


CREATE DATABASE escuela;


USE escuela;


CREATE TABLE alumnos(NO_LISTA int not null,NO_CONTROL VARCHAR(30) not null,NO_ALUMNO VARCHAR(50));



CREATE TABLE alumnos301(NO_LISTA int not null,NO_CONTROL VARCHAR(30) not null,NO_ALUMNO VARCHAR(50));





 CREATE TABLE maria_scarlett(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));


CREATE TABLE irvin_jesus(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));


CREATE TABLE edgar_isaac(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));


CREATE TABLE kevin_yahir(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE luis_david(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE mario_arturo(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE edgar_ivan(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE ernesto(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE jose_damian(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE aridaid(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE alan_israel(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE carlos_daniel(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE kenia_monserrat(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE alexis_daniel(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE rodrigo(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE merari_neftali(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE alan_rey(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE emmanuel(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));



CREATE TABLE vanessa_araceli(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));



CREATE TABLE alex_joan(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE eruviel(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE alvaro_antonio(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE katia(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE jesus_said(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE angel_isai(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));



CREATE TABLE luis_enrique(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE bernardo(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE abraham(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));



CREATE TABLE ailed_erandi(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE rocio(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE juan_manuel(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE itzel(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE alex_david(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));



CREATE TABLE luz_maria(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE david_axcel(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));



CREATE TABLE juan_jose(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));



CREATE TABLE miguel_angel(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));



CREATE TABLE sofia(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));




CREATE TABLE juan_jose(semestre VARCHAR(15),grupo VARCHAR(10),alumno VARCHAR(50),control VARCHAR(30),biologia1 VARCHAR(10),biologia2 VARCHAR(10),biologia3 VARCHAR(10),etica1 VARCHAR(10),etica2 VARCHAR(10),etica3 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica1 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica2 VARCHAR(10),geometria_analitica3 VARCHAR(10),ingles1 VARCHAR(10),ingles2 VARCHAR(10),ingles3 VARCHAR(10),submodulo11 VARCHAR(10),submodulo12 VARCHAR(10),submodulo13 VARCHAR(10),submodulo21 VARCHAR(10),submodulo22 VARCHAR(10),submodulo23 VARCHAR(10),asistencia VARCHAR(20),promedio VARCHAR(10),finales VARCHAR(50),extraodinarios VARCHAR(50));
```

Quiero mostrar los datos (biologia1,biologia2,biologia3) de la tabla de un alumno
ayudaaaaaaaaa!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Para ver la información que pides pondrías lo siguiente

```
SELECT biologia1, biologia2, biologia3

FROM el_alumno
```

Lo bueno que tiene mysql es la rica documentación que tiene, espero que te sea de ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: No me muestra nada solo pone empy set

Comment: ¿Que puedo hacer?

Comment: Copia y pega aqui la consulta que haces, y pon un comentario de lo que quieres, a ver si mi ejemplo no contesta a tu respuesta, o pones algo mal

Comment: debes darle formato a tu pregunta @juan pues no se entiende

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT biologia1, biologia2, biologia3 FROM nombre_alumno
```

Te mostrará los datos guardados en los respectivos campos de la tabla del alumno que requieres, solo te mostrará datos siempre y cuando tengas la correspondiente tabla poblada.